# Swift extend protocol by

Tags: swift, kotlin

Hello so I want to implement something similar in swift

Kotlin example:

```
class SessionManager(
    private val freeManager: FreeManager
) : FreeManager by freeManager 
{
}
```

up here FreeManager is Interface I pass reference through constructor and now I can write in extend part FreeManager by freeManager which doesn't require me to implement all methods from interface how can I achieve something similar in swift with protocols?

Can I do something like this:

```
class SessionManager : FreeManager {

init(freeManager: FreeManager) {
    // assign freeManager to extended protocol instead of implementing 
    //all needed methods from protocol
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you're looking for using a **`protocol`** and a **`protocol extension`**.

**1.** Create a `protocol` name `FreeManager` with 2 methods,

```
protocol FreeManager {
    func method1()
    func method2()
}
```

For now, both `method1()` and `method2()` are mandatory to implement by the `conforming type`.

`2.` Create a `protocol extension` and implement the method of `protocol` that you want to make `optional`, i.e.

```
extension FreeManager {
    func method2() {
        print("This is method2()")
    }
}
```

In the above code, I've implemented `method2()` in `protocol extension`. So, now implementing this method is `optional` for the `conforming type`. `method1()` is still mandatory to implement.

**3.** Conform class `SessionManager` to `FreeManager`

```
class SessionManager: FreeManager {
    func method1() {
        print("This is method1()")
    }
}
```

In the above code, I've implemented only `method1()`.

Comment: Good example, but it doesn't do what I want you see your example implements FreeManager functions in extension this is why it's not required to implement it anymore, but what I actually want is that freeManager which was passed through init would be used as default implementation of extended protocol

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re exactly looking for. Kindly specify the usecase.

Comment: @PGDev SessionManager automatically conforms by protocol FreeManager by using the instance variabele freeManager for fulfilling the protocol's contract

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can extend the protocol itself:

```
protocol Foo {
    func bar()
}

extension Foo {
    func bar() {
        print("bar")
    }
}

class Bar: Foo {
}

let bar = Bar()
bar.bar()
```